Python API: "AUTOSAVE" missing in bpy.utils.user_resource (version 4.2+)
Until version 4.2, there used to be an option to retrieve the default autosave path via the bpy.utils.user_resource. Now it's gone and I can't find in the docs any reference to what it was replaced with.
Anybody has any idea how to retrieve the path in the newer Blender versions?

In Blender 4.2+ autosaves are saved not into the "autosaves" folder, but into Temporary Folder
By default, it's the system's temporary folder (e.g., "C:\Temp" for Windows)
The temporary folder can be changed by user in preferences:
Edit > Preferences > File Paths > Temporary Files

(!) to get the temporary folder (where autosaves are stored) you can use the following code:
from os.path import dirname
from bpy.app import tempdir

autosave_path = dirname(dirname(tempdir))


Note I think by default if you're using a Linux distro the temp folder is wiped on computer restart.
